# Where I can find a good wordpress theme development tutorial?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Where I can find a good wordpress theme development tutorial? Something that is upgraded to the last versions of the WP API?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From scratch.. Are you sure?. If you really want to start from scratch this will get you started: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/08/how-to-code-a-wordpress-3-0-theme-from-scratch/

http://stylishwebdesigner.com/21-excellent-detailed-wordpress-theme-development-tutorials/

But do you know a lot of handy WP theme frameworks exist? They will speed up development with at least 60%. Most of them can be used for personal and commercial perpose! One of my favourites is: http://wpstartbox.com/

For a comparison of different WP frameworks see: http://wpcandy.com/presents/wordpress-theme-framework-comparison

Cheers!

Comment: thanks, I was thinking it was worth to start at least the first time from scratch since I don't know how WP API works, and i thought that it wouldn't have been to use a framework if i don't have at least a basic understanding of the API. Am i thinking wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Here are some popular resources where you can find comprehensive tutorials:

WordPress.org Theme Developer Handbook:
Website: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Udemy:
Website: https://www.udemy.com/

Wpacademy
Website: https://Wpacademy.pk